# Do these tags need an umbrella?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently [8 questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edge-of-the-empire+force-and-destiny+age-of-rebellion) that are tagged with all three of [edge-of-the-empire](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edge-of-the-empire), [force-and-destiny](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-and-destiny), and [age-of-rebellion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-rebellion). That's out of 44 EotE, 20 FaD, and 29 AoR questions. In other words, **a sizable proportion of questions in *any* of these tags have *all* of these tags.**

I don't know the system at all, but it seems to me that that somehow the three separate tags are overloaded. I mean, just from an information-theoretical standpoint it seems like those questions are devoting 3/5 of their tag-space and not getting much for it. Is one of these two things likely:

1. some of these questions need re-tagging?
2. we need an umbrella tag for the three related games?

Comment: Previous discussion: [Should there be a 'Parent tag' for the FFG Star Wars games?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5999/1204)

Comment: @doppelgreener hmm... do we dupe-close on meta? Or just leave it linked?

Comment: We can do dupe closure on meta. I haven't decided whether or not to yet, and just wanted to leave the link.